# Keyboard periodically locks on Ubuntu and GNOME 2

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, gnome

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 with GNOME 2.30.

Once every couple of days, I might be pressing something or doing something – I haven't found out what it is, though last time I was pressing the "mouse lock" button
on my on-board mouse on my laptop – my **keyboard simply locks down**.

Some keys work, like `ALT+CTRL+F1-6` and also `ALT+SHIFT` still changes the keyboard layout,
but everything else doesn't work, no letters, no other shortcuts.

To fix it, I go to `ALT+CTRL+F1` (Terminal) and run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

But I'm getting kinda tired of doing that every now and then. Any ideas if in Gnome there's a shortcut for "Kill my Keyboard" or something?

Comment: Do you use USB keyboard? I have similar problem, getting 'Unable to enumerate USB device…'

Comment: Please don't use `<br>`s to break lines. They're automatically wrapped.

Comment: I don't see that anybody has addressed the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your X server is getting confused, based on the facts that a) your keyboard gets you to a working console and b) killing X (via gdm) clears the trouble.

Unfortunately, stock Lucid disables the "Kill X Server" <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Backspace</kbd> sequence. Fortunately enabling it is easy System > Preferences > Keyboard > Options... > Key Squence to kill the X server.

Yes, you'll still be killing X, but it will be faster. `/var/log/Xorg.log.0` may give you some hints as to the failure, or perhaps syslog or dmesg or kern.log. Happy hunting.

Comment: Good stuff, msw.

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` is deprecated...use the Magic SysRQ Key instead: `Alt+Print+K`.